# I need to expand a simple grammar currently parsed with a Regex

Tags: regex

I am doing some text processing in C#. I need to extract elements from a text string which have the form:

```
pre-text[var1|2|3]in-text[vara|b|c]post-text
```

Later on in processing I replace these bracketed expressions with values from a data store. The general form is best expressed as a regular expression (two line feeds added for clarity):

```
\[(?<var>[^]|]+)\]|
\[(?<var>[^]|]+)\|(?<fmt>[^]|]+)\]|
\[(?<var>[^]|]+)\|(?<fmt>[^]|]+)\|(?<txt>[^]|]+)\]
```

So, if I want to include a date from the database and format it, I can create a template such as:

```
We are looking forward to seeing you at your next clinic visit on
[$event_datetime|D] at [$event_datetime|h:mm tt] at the Center.
```

After straightforward processing, this becomes:

```
We are looking forward to seeing you at your next clinic visit on 
Tuesday, June 30, 2015 at 5:30 PM at the Center
```

Applying the regular expression gives me all of the positioning, variable, and formatting information I need.

What I would like to do now is to be able to nest (a single level) another variable reference inside of a variable reference. For example, if I want to create a data reference for "field_001", I currently need to reference something like:

```
[field_001]
```

Instead, I want to be able to specify:

```
[field_[$occurrence|000]]
```

I retain all of the matches resulting from parsing with the regex and then perform the replacements once the data is available. With this new feature, I expect I will need to keep two sets of matches, performing the nested replacements first and then the outer replacements.

So, start with a string such as:

```
This string is your [field_[$occurrence|000]]!
```

So the first pass, replacing all of the inner data references will give me, (assuming the value of "$occurrence" is 1) a string: "001", which I would then substitute into the outer variable reference, after which point I will look up the new variable name, "field_001" to get it's value.

The second replacement will give me, assuming the value of "field_001" is "string":

```
This string is your string!
```

But I am having trouble coming up with the required regex. I also suspect my current regex is not optimal and would be glad to hear how to improve it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide a sample new string *with* expected output. I believe you just need an optional group inside your current regex so as to match another optional bracketed substring, no need for balanced construct stack here.

Comment: After the update, it is still unclear how we can help you. sln suggested a solution based on replacing the `[...]` substrings having no `[` and `]` inside in a loop, and perhaps, that is the best what you can get. I doubt you really need a monstrous regex with recursion/balanced construct (if you think you need, you may ask, but we need to know your regex flavor). Note that a lot of people do not consider answering regex questions like this with no language tag, as it makes it unclear what options you might have.

Comment: What programming language is this in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case, like you say, if doing nesting it's better to do the
inner to outer substitutions.

This requires sitting in a while loop where each pass starts the
process from the beginning with the modified string.

An example for PHP would be something like:

```
$strSrc = " ... ";
$found = 1;

while ( $found )
{
    $found = 0;
    $strSrc = preg_replace_callback('the regex',
         function( $matches )
         {
             $found = 1;
             $repl = "initial string replacement";
             if ( $matches["var"] )
             {
                 // add to $repl
             }
             if ( $matches["fmt"] )
             {
                 // add to $repl
             }
             if ( $matches["txt"] )
             {
                 // add to $repl
             }
             return $repl;
         },
         $strSrc
     );
}
```

The accompanied raw regex would be:

```
\[(?<var>[^\[\]|]+)(?:\|(?<fmt>[^\[\]|]+)(?:\|(?<txt>[^\[\]|]+))?)?\]
```

Stringed:

```
'~\[(?<var>[^\[\]|]+)(?:\|(?<fmt>[^\[\]|]+)(?:\|(?<txt>[^\[\]|]+))?)?\]~'
```

Formated/Expanded:

```
 \[
 (?<var> [^\[\]|]+ )           # (1), Var
 (?:                           # Optional fmt
      \|
      (?<fmt> [^\[\]|]+ )           # (2), Fmt
      (?:                           # Optional txt
           \|
           (?<txt> [^\[\]|]+ )           # (3), Txt
      )?
 )?
 \]
```

***edit***
To allow escaped brackets use this -

Raw:

```
\[(?<var>[^\[\]\\|]*(?:\\.[^\[\]\\|]*)*)(?:\|(?<fmt>[^\[\]\\|]*(?:\\.[^\[\]\\|]*)*)(?:\|(?<txt>[^\[\]\\|]*(?:\\.[^\[\]\\|]*)*))?)?\]
```

Stringed:

```
'~\[(?<var>[^\[\]\\\|]*(?:\\\.[^\[\]\\\|]*)*)(?:\|(?<fmt>[^\[\]\\\|]*(?:\\\.[^\[\]\\\|]*)*)(?:\|(?<txt>[^\[\]\\\|]*(?:\\\.[^\[\]\\\|]*)*))?)?\]~'
```

Formatted

```
 \[
 (?<var>                       # (1 start), Var
      [^\[\]\\|]* 
      (?: \\ . [^\[\]\\|]* )*
 )                             # (1 end)
 (?:                           # Optional fmt
      \|
      (?<fmt>                       # (2 start), Fmt
           [^\[\]\\|]* 
           (?: \\ . [^\[\]\\|]* )*
      )                             # (2 end)
      (?:                           # Optional txt
           \|
           (?<txt>                       # (3 start), Txt
                [^\[\]\\|]* 
                (?: \\ . [^\[\]\\|]* )*
           )                             # (3 end)
      )?
 )?
 \]
```

Comment: This fails if one of the bracketed expressions expands to `[foo]` (it will be re-expanded).

Comment: @melpomene -  I don't understand what you mean, are you saying _substitute_ `[foo]` with `[bar]` ? I hope not, that defeats the purpose doesn't it .. More likely, it would be replaced with `bar`. It doesn't matter though, continued passes should (must) eventually resolve to a value other than a bracketed variable. If not designed that way, might as well run `while(1)`

Comment: Thanks for the shorter regex and the "non-capturing group" usage! This method works by not matching on references containing nested references and repeating the application of the pattern until there are no matches. Looks like a winner to me. Thank you. I'll accept once I figure out how to use this.

Is it too late to ask how to allow escaped brackets in the text, e.g., "\\[" and "\\]" or should that be a new question?

Comment: @David Rogers - Yeah, just replace `[^\[\]|]+` with `[^\[\]\\|]*(?:\\.[^\[\]\\|]*)*`, I've added it above.